# Is there a way to set the alignment of the cells?

Tags: fieldbook

When you enter values (text, number, generic, etc) into cells they automatically align themselves to a preset direction. This is especially bad in situations where some of the cells do contain more than one value separated with commas in them because those cells align their content to the opposite direction.

The GUI doesn't present you an option to set the cell content alignment. There may be some code based solutions.

Is there a way to set the alignment of the cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a direct way to set the alignment of cells, but at a column level, you can set the cell type.  Numbers format to the right, and text formats to the left as in a normal spreadsheet.

If you set the type for a column, it will apply to all cells in the column.

[image: screen shot of type setting]

Generic is the default, text will format to the left and number to the right.  Note that if set the column type to text, and then use it in a formula, you might get unexpected results (for instance a Text '1' + 1 will result in 11, not 2.

[image: Type Chooser]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It's nice to meet someone on SE community who uses Fieldbook. Unfortunately I can't select your answer as the solution because this doesn't exactly solve my problem. I want to keep the type of my cells whilst setting their alignment. It can be that Fieldbook developers haven't enabled such a setting yet. I was (and still am) hoping that there is an undocumented code based solution for it.

Comment: Actually, I'm the CTO of Fieldbook :), so yeah, no way to do this currently.  We love getting user feedback about why they want certain features, though, you can always hit 'Message Us' to ask us about how to do things.  I don't think this is one we've heard of before, but definitely going on the list.

Comment: I should also add that you might be able to do this with a user style sheet, but again, would be difficult to make it only apply to certain cells instead of just, for instance, all numbers.  Do you want certain numbers to be left justified and certain ones to be right justified?

Comment: Wow meeting the developer of Fieldbook himself :) You've edited your profile while I was commenting on your post. It's nice to have you here. Let the question session begin :) - The CTO is nice to have, too :)))

Comment: And of course in this case your answer is the solution. Nice to have you here.